# 'GalaxyUser' object has no attribute 'backend' error in Django?

Tags: django, authentication

I have a `login` function with custom `authenticate` function.

```
def authenticate(username='username', password='password'):
    try:
        return GalaxyUser.objects.get(username=username, password=password)
    except GalaxyUser.DoesNotExist:
        return None

def login_backend(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        username1 = ''.join(username)
        password = request.POST['password']
        password = ''.join(password)
        password1 = hashlib.sha1(password).hexdigest()
        user = authenticate(username=username1, password=password1)
        login(request, user)
        if user is None:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/unsuccessful/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/successful/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('login_backend.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I am not redirected to successful or unsuccessful. However, I get this error:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/zurelsoft/workspace/genelaytics/fileupload/backend.py" in login_backend
  21.         login(request, user)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in login
  73.     request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY] = user.backend

Exception Type: AttributeError at /login_backend/
Exception Value: 'GalaxyUser' object has no attribute 'backend'
```

What am I doing wrong? `GalaxyUser` is my model name and `backend` is where my view code is.

Answer (score 0):

Because your authenticate function is a standalone function, rather than a class that implements the authentication backend API as specified [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend).